# How do I reduce the two-tab indent of multi-line statements to one tab in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tabs, editor, tabbing

For instance, if I'm defining a StringBuffer and I append to the constructor, it will give me two tabs on the append:

```
Foobar sb = new Foobar()
        .append(condition ? "Content" : "Other content")
        .append(conditional ? "More content" : "Even more content");
```

I want only one tab, which makes sense because I'm never going to tab something after the initial line of Foobar unless it's in a block, so the second tab is entirely pointless:

```
Foobar sb = new Foobar()
    .append(condition ? "Content" : "Other content")
    .append(conditional ? "More content" : "Even more content");
```

I looked through the Editor settings for Java in Preferences and could only find a way to insert tabs as spaces, which I would never do (I love my tabs).

Comment: editor? what editor tabs? Why are you using `StringBuffer` many trheads access this StringBuffer? Use `StringBuilder`

Comment: StringBuffer was just an example, it could be anything. It could be the Foobar class for all I care. But yes, it is a multi-threaded environment and I need to use StringBuffer.

Comment: i didn't understand your question, are you talking about `code indentation`?

Comment: so you don't like the way eclipse indent code? `ctrl+i` indent your code..

Comment: Back to default, which is two tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of Eclipse you're on, but on 4.3, you should be able to set up custom style formatter (or edit existing ones) from Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter. Then create a new custom profile or edit an existing one.

On the actual profile edit window, it'll be under the Line Wrapping tab, then the "Default indentation for wrapped lines" option on the left.

Comment: This answer deserves so many more upvotes than I can give it. I had to reset Eclipse some time ago and I lost my formatting profile. I actually ended up finding this via a Google search, because I didn't remember I had asked the question!